# Custom NSCell not handling correct row (NSTableView)

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstableview

I am kinda new to Cocoa Development. I have a NSTableView with a custom NSCell which contains two NSButtonCell and also a custom object.

When tableview objectValue is triggered I get this cell and set a custom object for each cell, then when cell drawWithFrame is triggered, I set the action for each button based on this custom object.

Everything works fine... However, I must 'select' the row before clicking on any button. If for example, I select the third row and click directly on the button on the first row, it will trigger the selected row function instead...

Since it is a customized NSCell, could it be related to the way I draw the NSRect and handle the clicks on them?

Comment: You are highly encouraged to use a view based table view. It makes life so much easier. Cell based table views are outdated.

Comment: I understand, but this is an old project. I must use NSCell :(

Comment: Must it really? View based table views have been introduced in 2011 (macOS 10.7).

Comment: Yes, I know. Unfortunately this one is using 10.4. Furthermore, I am just trying to add a new customized NSCell to it

Comment: How do you handle the clicks on them?

Comment: @Willeke, inside the init method of my cell subclass, I add to each button target=self and the action will be a selector of this cell subclass. This method (used in selector) will call a method from my custom object (this custom object I set during tableview objetValue call) I can edit my question with code if you think it would help

Comment: A [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help.